# What is . get() function can do in python for others than dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

There is a part in **django**

```
@html_safe
class BaseForm:
    ---------------------------
    @property
    def errors(self):
        """Return an ErrorDict for the data provided for the form."""
        if self._errors is None:
            self.full_clean()
        return self._errors
    ---------------------------
    def non_field_errors(self):
        """
        Return an ErrorList of errors that aren't associated
    with a particular
        field -- i.e., from Form.clean(). Return an empty 
    ErrorList if there
        are none.
        """
        return self.errors.get(NON FIELD ERRORS, self.error_class(error_class='nonfield'))
```

I know *get()* works with dictionary.
But I have seen mane time *get()* is working on class properties like here.

Comment: Since you are talking about Django, did you try looking at the Django docs? If it is not there, for all we know it might be custom to the project you copied this code from.

Comment: Yes I have pick this code right from Django docs.

Answer (score 0):

I have some research on this topic and I got to know, in this

```
         return self.errors.get(NON FIELD ERRORS, self.error_class(error_class='nonfield'))
```

`self.errors` is the `def errors(self):` which is passed to the decorator `@property`.
that's why when it is called by `self.errors` it returning the `def errors()` function's return and because the **return type is a dictionary** that's why there is .get() function at `self.errors.get()`.

Thereafter the conclusion is `.get()` works with ***dictionary({}) data type***